# How do I document symbols with a depth greater than 2 in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have an object that contains multiple methods and is a member of a class. How would I document this with JSDoc?

Here's my attempt. With this `SomeClass#helperFunctions` is documented, but both of it's methods are omitted.

```js
/**
 * @class SomeClass
 * @param name
 */
var SomeClass = function(name) {};

/**
 * @member SomeClass#helperFunctions
 */
SomeClass.prototype.helperFunctions = {
  /**
   * @method SomeClass#helperFunctions.doSomething
   * @param {Array} arr
   */
  doSomething: function(arr) {}
};

/**
 * @method SomeClass#helperFunctions.doSomethingElse
 * @param {Array} arr
 */
SomeClass.protype.helperFunctions.doSomethingElse = function(arr) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with.

I document methods of `SomeClass#helperFunctions` as globals then include them as properties of `SomeClass#helperFunctions` using links.

```
/**
 * @class SomeClass
 * @param {String} name
 */
var SomeClass = function(name) {};

/**
 * @member SomeClass#helperFunctions
 * @property {Function} doSomething [_doSomething]{@link _doSomething}
 * @property {Function} doSomethingElse [_doSomethingElse]{@link _doSomethingElse}
 */
SomeClass.prototype.helperFunctions = {
  doSomething: _doSomething,
  doSomethingElse: _doSomethingElse
};

/**
 * @function _doSomething
 * @param {Array} arr
 */
_doSomething = function(arr) {};

/**
 * @function _doSomethingElse
 * @param {Array} arr
 */
_doSomethingElse = function(arr) {};
```

---

In my actual application `SomeClass` was also a module so it was written as:

```
/**
 * @module path/to/SomeClass
 */

/**
 * @class module:path/to/SomeClass
 */
var SomeClass = module.exports = function() {};
```

Then the links were written as `{@link module:path/to/SomeClass~_doSomething}` so it would link to it's spot on the module page instead of looking for them in Globals.